# Using Alert.show in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

In Flex 3, when I use

```
Alert.show("some text");
```

I will get an alert message along with the OK button. When I press the OK button I get another alert message. I have tried the following code, but it's not working.

```
Alert.show(" Simulation for " + id_formulator.nme + " Campaign", null, mx.controls.Alert.OK, this, alertListener, null, mx.controls.Alert.OK);

private function alertListener(eventObj:Event):void {
    if (eventObj.detail == mx.controls.Alert.OK) {
        Alert.show("next message");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question and elaborate on what you want to achieve? Do you want the second alert TO BE displayed after the first one, or NOT TO BE displayed?

Comment: By the way, to format a code block in a post, you can indent it four spaces, or select it and click the code button (101010) on the editor's toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in your function alertListener, you declared the parameter eventObj to be of type Event. The Event class doesn't have a detail field. However, the CloseEvent subclass does. It also happens to be the type of the event dispatched by an Alert being closed.

Also, you can only use the this keyword in a context where it has scope. So you need to wrap it inside an initialize function (rather than just float in static code. You'll need to add `initialize="showAlerts()"` to the window in order for it to happen when the window is opened. Otherwise, just replace with your event of choice

Additionally, I would suggest using the import directive, since it makes your code significantly shorter, and short code is easier to maintain.

So your code should be:

```
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.events.CloseEvent;

private function showAlerts():void {
    Alert.show("Simulation for " + id_formulator.nme + " Campaign", null, Alert.OK, this, alertListener, null, Alert.OK);
}

private function alertListener(eventObj:CloseEvent):void {
    if (eventObj.detail == Alert.OK) {
        Alert.show("next message");
    }
}
```